# Hyperlink OnClick event in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create an `OnClick` event for hyperlink control?

Can we use `Attributes.Add("OnClick","eventname")`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The event is onclick.

You can add it to the hyperlink's mark-up or in the code-behind file.

Mark-up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function handleHyperLinkClick(hyperlink) {

            return confirm("Do you want to navigate to " + hyperlink.href + " ?");
        }
</script>

<asp:HyperLink ID='HyperLink1' runat="server" onclick='return handleHyperLinkClick(this)' Text='Click Me' NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

code-behind:

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return handleHyperLinkClick(this)");
```

Comment: don't see the `onclick` method for the tag :/